# Table for Binary Operations

Tags: tables, math-operators

I am trying to build a table used for different binary operations, especially with thicker lines on the sides separating the elements in the set from the "products" of the operations.  I know this question already exists, but I cannot find it anymore.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We need a pitcure of what you want if we are to help you. I'm pretty sure that "I would like a table of binary operators" doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn,leqno,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand\thickvrule{\vrule width 1pt}

\newcommand\thickhrule{\Xhline{1pt}}
\begin{document}

 \[ \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{array}{!{\thickvrule}r!{\thickvrule}c|c|c!{\thickvrule}}
\thickhrule
        \times & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\thickhrule
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
        1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
        2 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
\thickhrule
    \end{array}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]